# Resource usage in nodelabel jobs

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop-2.7.2

I am using Hadoop 2.7.2. Is there any way I can measure the resource usage in the jobs running in nodelabel? I am looking for a way to get this through jmx.

I want to see how much usage is there in nodelabel and scale/descale accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can access Yarn Resource Manager web UI through port no. 8088 and if you want to access jmx report then simply enter 8088/jmx.

Eg: 192.1.1.1:8080/jmx ( For jmx report)

192.1.1.1:8088 ( For resource manager UI)

Comment: I am aware of this option. I am able to get the resource usage of each queue. I am looking for the usage in the nodelabel.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?